# Probability to find treasure

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

You have a metal detector that will beep 99 times out of 100 if it contains buried treasure within a metre squared. It will also beep 1 time in a 100 if it does not contain buried treasure. I'm searching an island containing John last hidden treasure. You have divided the island up into 1,001 1 metre by 1 metre squares which you plan to test individually. On the first square the metal detector beeps. What is the chance that you've discovered the treasure?

I have no idea how to tackle this problem. Would you like to help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Let $B$ denotes the event that the metal detector beeps.

Let $T$ denote the event that there is treassure.

Now apply Bayes rule on $P(T|B)=\frac{P(T)P(B|T)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(T)P(B|T)}{P(T)P(B|T)+P(T^c)P(B|T^c)}$.

You will have to make some assumption, such as the treassure only appears in exactly one of the squares.

Comment: Let assume that it can appear in exactly one of the squares. How we can work out the full solution?

Comment: First you work out $P(T)$ and $P(B|T)$ and $P(B|T^c)$.

Comment: Can you give me hand to work out this probabilities please?

Comment: I want to help you to grow. Can you tell me where are you stuck?

Comment: I am not sure the value of $P(T)P(B|T)$? I cannot work out this.

Comment: First, for $P(T)$, you have $1001$ squares, only one of them contain treassure, can you make a guess? For $P(B|T)$, read the first sentence of the question again.

Comment: So if i work it out correctly it is $\dfrac{1}{1001}\times\dfrac{99}{100}$ right?

Comment: congrats, you have worked out the numerator, you just have to work out the denominator and you are done.

Comment: This the whole expression $\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{1001}\times\dfrac{99}{100}}{\dfrac{1}{1001}\times\dfrac{99}{100} + \dfrac{1000}{1001}\times\dfrac{1}{100}}$ which yields to $\dfrac{99}{1099}$.

Comment: congratulations

Comment: Really appreciate your support and patience. Super kudos you are born to be teacher.